# Не работают import/export в node.js. Как исправить?

Tags: node.js

Прописал в package.json "type":"module" но все равно ипорты не работают. Появляется
ошибка.

````
 import cli from '../src/cli';
       ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at createDynamicModule (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:73:15)
    at Object.meta.done (internal/modules/esm/create_dynamic_module.js:40:9)
    at file:///home/xazret/frontend-project-lvl1/bin/brain-games.js:9:13
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:95:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)```
````

Comment: какая версия nodejs? `import cli from '../src/cli.js` решает проблему?

Comment: Версия v10.19.0
```import cli from '../src/cli.js``` не работает

Comment: в 10 версии и подход был не такими, https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/esm.html

Comment: эмм а cli то экспортируется из компонента?

Comment: Спасибо всем, обновление версий node решило проблему))